# debian source package code structure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I want to know where to find the information about the code structure of any debian package like e.g bash,gawk,grep or any other package.
If we open the source code directory we find some similar folders in each of them like m4,po or tests etc.
what every folder is meant for ?
Specially the "tests" folder ,can we test each package with this "tests"  folder.Simply i want to know all information for source code packages.